# Get Hyper-V VM Tag

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

I can set a tag for the VM through Windows Admin Center, but I can't find how to view this tag through powershell.

I need this for a script so that I take all VM names with a specific tag

UPD:
I am using hyper-v server core 2019

Comment: Have you looked at output of `Get-VM`? Try `Get-VM | fl *` to list all properties.

Comment: @zett42 Unfortunately, there is neither the tag property nor the value that I specified in the windows admin center [screen1](https://paste.pics/JDM2J) [screen2](https://paste.pics/JDM44)

Comment: Then it's possibly a Windows Admin Center specific thing. As a workaround you might use the Notes property, which is accessible through PowerShell.

Comment: @zett42it's it's a good idea, but I can't figure out how to take just the names and stuff them into a file. I tried it, but I only need names, and I don't understand how to do it...
`$VMs = Get-VM | Where-Object {$_.Notes -match "mytag"} | Select-Object Name` and `$VMs | Out-File ./vms.txt`

[out-file](https://paste.pics/JDO7H)

Comment: `$VMs = Get-VM | Where-Object Notes -match "mytag" | Select-Object -Expand Name`

Comment: @zett42 Thanks, [you are breathtaking](https://paste.pics/JDPCU)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @zett42, I solved the problem, albeit in a different way

```
$vm = Get-VM my_vm
$vm | Set-VM -Notes "mytag" -Confirm:$false
$VMs = Get-VM | Where-Object Notes -match "mytag" | Select-Object -Expand Name
$VMs | Out-File ./vms.txt
```